# can't use bloc observer after bloc update

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit

I have a problem with the last update of bloc 8.0.1 I can't use the bloc observer and I used the BlocOverrides and still not working and here is my code

[my main class code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EmHb.jpg)

`BlocObserver`

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

class MyBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onCreate(BlocBase bloc) {
    super.onCreate(bloc);
    print('onCreate -- ${bloc.runtimeType}');
  }

  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    print('onChange -- ${bloc.runtimeType}, $change');
  }

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    print('onError -- ${bloc.runtimeType}, $error');
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
  }

  @override
  void onClose(BlocBase bloc) {
    super.onClose(bloc);
    print('onClose -- ${bloc.runtimeType}');
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Undefined name 'BlocOverrides'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Comment: this is my main class code https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EmHb.jpg

Comment: and I have either this error 
The class 'BlocObserver' is abstract and can't be instantiated.
  static BlocObserver observer = BlocObserver();

Comment: have you imported import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart'; this?

Comment: try running Flutter clean and pub get if even it's showing then just restart your code editor

Comment: thanks for caring the problem was my dart version is old and i have upgraded it and it's run

Comment: pleased to hear

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the next code.

```
 BlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () => runApp(const App()),
    blocObserver: AppBlocObserver(),
 );
```

You can see it on the flutter package example. I had the same problem as you, but with this change, everything works correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line in your main()

```
Bloc.observer = MyBlocObserver();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem was with dependencies, use

```
   flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
```

and import it package to main and MyBlocObserver class

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
```

this is worked for me. Here is little project that I used [click](https://github.com/Abduboriy3444/learn_bloc)